# How to declare out parameter in c# for T_NARRAY output in Oracle?

Tags: c#, oracle, user-defined-types

While execute I am getting a `data type binding error`.
The Oracle script is returning `T_Narray OUT_PUT`, Which I don't know how to handle it on c# out parameter.

> dbManager.AddOutputParameters(1, "P_RESULT_ARRAY", "",
>   OracleDbType.Raw,  100);

How to do ?

My Proc:

```
 PROCEDURE D_ARRAY
  (
    P_SOURCE               IN NVARCHAR2,
    P_RESULT_ARRAY         OUT T_NARRAY,
    P_RESULT_STATUS        OUT NVARCHAR2,
    P_RESULT_STATUS_TEXT   OUT NVARCHAR2 
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`T_NARRAY` is a user-defined type. That is, it is an object defined in the database. You need to define a custom type in C# which matches the database definition. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/featUDTs.htm#ODPNT377).

You can investigate the structure of the user-defined type by querying the Oracle data dictionary: [ALL_TYPES](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2112.htm#REFRN20298) and [ALL_TYPE_ATTRS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2109.htm#REFRN20295).